# How do a I create a Set valued column in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In the Spark Shell I am trying to make a Set valued column, but Spark interprets the Set as an array.

```
scala> var df=List((Set(1,2),1,2), (Set(2,1),2,1)).toDF("s","a","b")
scala> df.show()
+------+---+---+
|     s|  a|  b|
+------+---+---+
|[1, 2]|  1|  2|
|[2, 1]|  2|  1|
+------+---+---+
scala> df.select("s")
res02: String = [s: array<int>]
```

How can I have a Set valued column in spark?

Comment: Which Spark version are you using? The list of available column types for a column is given here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/package-summary.html , so you need a user defined type but I think this was removed for Spark 2.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14155

Comment: This particular REPL was at version 2.3.1. I am also using 2.3.2.

Comment: Not sure it is actually possible.